# How to get a writable Stream to send content to an HTTP server in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, http, httpclient

I've been able to read raw binary content from an HTTP API using this:

```
var response = httpClient.GetStreamAsync("http://...");
```

But how to do the same **for writing**?

So far, I've found no way to get an open `Stream` to write asyncronously to the server.

The method `HttpClient.PostAsync(...)` isn't useful for me, because it will take control over the read-write process to the server.

My goal is to have a `Stream` to which I can write, like any other stream.

Is this even possible?

Comment: Someone with your rep. should know how to research before asking!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a little difficult to do what you want using the current API.

Depending on your requirement, you may want to just *pass* an existing stream. In which case use `StreamContent`. Note that the stream needs to be filled (or otherwise fully readable) at the point the call is made. For example you can pass a `FileStream` this way.

```
using var fs = new FileStream("someFile");
using var message = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://someurl.com");
message.Content = new StreamContent(fs);
using var resp = await _client.SendAsync(message);
// etc
```

This would be the easiest way to send most requests, as you normally have another stream you are sending.

---

If you want to be able to intercept the call to retrieve the stream and fill it then it's a bit more complicated. You need to create your own `HttpContent` class, implementing at least the minimum overrides necessary. An example is given in [the documentation for `HttpContent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpcontent?view=net-7.0#examples).

Answer (score 2):

Looking into the `HttpContent` class this should actually be somewhat easily implemented. You can make your own implementation where you use a callback method. This callback will then get invoked with the `Stream` you need to write to.

Implementation:

```
public class HttpContentCallback : HttpContent
{
    private readonly Func<Stream, Task> _callback;

    public HttpContentCallback(Func<Stream, Task> callback)
    {
        _callback = callback;
    }

    protected override Task SerializeToStreamAsync(Stream stream, TransportContext? context)
    {
        return _callback(stream);
    }

    protected override bool TryComputeLength(out long length)
    {
        length = 0;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Great answer. Adding `CancellationToken` support might be wise.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the `HttpClient` class support writing to a stream in the way that you want, you would have to use the older `HttpWebRequest` class.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;

internal class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string filePath = "C:/example.bin"; 
        string uploadUrl = "http://example.com/upload"; 
        
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uploadUrl);        
        request.Method = "POST";        
        request.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
        
        byte[] fileData = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
        request.ContentLength = fileData.Length;
        
        using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            int bufferSize = 4096; 
            int bytesWritten = 0; 
            while (bytesWritten < fileData.Length)
            {
                int bytesToWrite = Math.Min(bufferSize, fileData.Length - bytesWritten); 
                requestStream.Write(fileData, bytesWritten, bytesToWrite); 
                bytesWritten += bytesToWrite; 
            }
        }
        
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        
        using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
        }
        
        response.Close();
    }
}
```

Please note that [Microsoft recommends](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest?view=net-7.0) that you do not use this class in new development.

However, this question may be an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

If your underlying problem is "how do I implement a progress bar" and you are asking for help with implementing your solution which is "use a stream in a loop" then there is an alternative solution for implementing a progress bar that works just fine with the `HTTPClient` class.

```
private async Task UploadFileWithProgress(string url, string filePath)
{
    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead(filePath))
        {
            var content = new StreamContent(fileStream);
            content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data")
            {
                FileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath)
            };
            content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");

            var progressContent = new ProgressableStreamContent(content, 4096, UploadProgressCallback);
            var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, progressContent);
            var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Console.WriteLine(responseContent);
        }
    }
}

private void UploadProgressCallback(long bytesUploaded, long totalBytes)
{
    // Update progress bar here
}
```